# WPF exception adding new Resource Dictionary

Tags: wpf, uri, resourcedictionary

I need to add some `ResourceDictionary` to a `WPF` window.

If I do as follow, everything works:

```
        var uri = $@"..\..\..\Assets\Styles";

        if (Directory.Exists(uri))
        {
            var allFile = Directory.GetFiles(uri);

            if (allFile == null) return;

            foreach (var file in allFile)
            {
                backupManagementWindow.MergeResourceDictionary(new Uri(file, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            }
        }
```

Since that I don't want to define the `Uri` based on my executable directory, I define it as follow:

```
var uri = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Assets\Styles";
```

The Uri is correct (there are the files) but then the code raise an exception.

```
    public void MergeResourceDictionary(Uri uriResource)
    {
        var newResource = new ResourceDictionary {Source = uriResource};
        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(newResource);
    }
```

Does anyone know why? Thanks!

Comment: would be useful to know what exception you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Pack Uri Scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx) when working with resource dictionaries.

And your uri would look something like this:

> The following example shows the pack URI for a XAML resource file that is located in a subfolder of the referenced assembly's project folder.
>
> `pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml`

Comment: Yes, as you wrote I have to consider the path starting from the assembly folder as specified here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(VS.85).aspx. Instead, I used the full path of the application. Thank you.